# Having trouble setting up Multiple emails notification through a process

Tags: workflow

Having trouble setting up a work flow for multiple email notification throughout a process. So i have created 3 work flows for this. Tested and everything and all of it seems to be working. The problem is when it workflow2 is completed it will run workflow 1 and send and email again on 1. So if workflow3 is completed and triggers an email it will resend email notification on workflow2 and 1 again.

Current Process
Workflow 1- If "Person 1 Complete" Then Email Trigger
Workflow 2- If "Person 2 Complete" Then Email Trigger
Workflow 3- If "Person 3 Complete" Then Email Trigger

Currently its working like this:

If Workflow 2 Completed Emails - Send Emails, reruns Workflow 1 send Emails
If Workflow 3 Completed Emails- Sends Emails, Reruns Workflow 2 send Emails, Reruns Workflow 1.

I only want it to send an email once after each step is completed. Any help out there is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to build these a separate workflows. You simply need to place a Wait action after you start your workflow. To prevent the next approval from starting simply add a new variable to your list (call it Status) and update the status based on the outcome of the preceding approval.

So you might have something like this;

```
Start Approval 1 process on Current Item with Email 1
then Wait for Approval Status to not equal 2;#Pending
then Set Status to Approval Status_1

"Approval Status_1" is a concatenated string with a _1 appended to the end to indicate that this is the status of the first approval step

If Status equals 0;#Approved_1
Start Approval 2 process on Current Item with Email 2
then Wait for Approval Status to not equal 2;#Pending
then Set Status to Approval Status_2

If Status equals 0;#Approved_2
Start Approval 3 process on *Current Item* with Email 3
then Wait for Approval Status to not equal 2;#Pending
then Set Status to Approval Status_3

If Status equals 0;#Approved_3
Send E-mail
```

To stop the whole workflow starting again you might want to set the Status variable to Complete or Rejected and test for these conditions before starting any approvals.

```
If Status is not equal to Completed
or Status is not equal to Rejected
Step through approvals
```

Or turn off workflow "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed"

Cheers unibod50

Comment: @Tom did this answer your question?